# How to open my Google account and my Google Apps account at the same time?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-account

I have a "normal" Google account I use privately and I have a company account on Google Apps. Since yesterday, it was possible to open both, side by side in two tabs of my browser. When I try this now, I get a message that I'm already signed in and I have the options to cancel or switch accounts.

My question is: How to open my Google account and my Google Apps account at the same time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One solution is to [activate "multiple sign-in"](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=181599) on your accounts. Afterwards you can use two tabs like before.

Another solution is to use different browser instances that do not share cookies. This can be done by starting the same browser multiple times, use different browsers (e.g. Chrome for one account, Firefox for another) or use something like [Prism](http://prism.mozillalabs.com/) to create dedicated instances.

Comment: I use multiple sign-in all the time at work so easy just make sure you login in with the one you use most first

Answer (score 5):

Another solution to that is to login to your Google Apps account in an [incognito window](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95464) if you are using Chrome or something similar in other browsers.

Comment: Well, when you use Chrome's incognito or Firefox's private browsing (summarized "porn mode"), you lose a couple of options for example you can't use "remember me" functions and no history is created.