# How to login in two accounts in the same browser?

Tags: gmail, google-account

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to open my Google account and my Google Apps account at the same time?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17235/how-to-open-my-google-account-and-my-google-apps-account-at-the-same-time)

I want to login in two users to Gmail using IE.

The problem is that even when I open a new instance the already logged in user will be logged in. And when I log out then the other instance will be logged off.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

[This document explains how to do this](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/access-two-gmail-accounts-at-once-in.html).

Edit: Here's the key instructions copied from that location:

> I have a couple different Gmail addresses that I use for different
>   purposes. Historically, Google Accounts – including Gmail accounts —
>   have only let people access one account at a time per browser, so
>   using both accounts has been a bit inconvenient. I’ve either had to
>   sign out and sign back in, use a second browser for my second account,
>   or use a Chrome incognito window. And I'm not alone; lots of people
>   have asked us for a better way to use multiple accounts at once in the
>   same browser.
>
> Now, you can visit [google.com/accounts](http://www.google.com/accounts) and click the link next to
>   "Multiple sign-in." After you sign into your first account, you can
>   sign in with up to two additional accounts from the new accounts menu
>   in the upper right hand corner of Gmail, then easily toggle back and
>   forth between them. You can even open multiple Gmail tabs — one for
>   each of your accounts.
>
> Please keep in mind that this is a feature for advanced users, and
>   there are a couple things to watch out for:
>
> 1. Not all Google [services support multiple account sign-in yet](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181602). For
>      the services that don't support it (like Blogger and Picasa Web
>      Albums), you'll be defaulted to the first account you signed in with
>      during that browser session. So if you click a link from Gmail to
>      Blogger, for example, you'll be logged into Blogger with the first
>      account you signed in with, even if you clicked the link to Blogger
>      from your second Gmail account.
> 2. We’re still working on making Gmail and Calendar work offline with
>      multiple sign-in. If you rely on offline access, you probably don't
>      want to enable this feature quite yet.
> 3. Multiple account sign-in only works on desktop browsers for now, so
>      if you use Gmail on your phone's browser you won't see this option
>      yet.
>
> Since Google Apps customers can already sign in to their accounts at
>   the same time as their personal Google Accounts, we won’t be adding
>   this new feature to Google Apps until the [new infrastructure](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2010/05/more-google-applications-coming-for.html) is in
>   place.
>
> If you use more than one Google Account, we hope this makes you more
>   efficient. If you have any questions, check out our [help center](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=181599).

Comment: I personally often just have two different browsers running anyway. Obviously you can go that route too. But you said you wanted them both in IE. So, go with the info in the above link about Multiple Sign In.

Comment: Can you summarize the contents of the link in your answer? If the blog link ever breaks, your answer would become useless. We're trying to make Stack Exchange as self-contained as possible. Thanks!

Comment: @Anna Lear - done, how's that better?

Comment: It's better because now if Google changes the structure of their links and doesn't bother redirecting the current ones, your answer is still helpful. Even if the links stay the same, someone can still find your answer and use it straightaway without having to leave Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to go to https://www.google.com/accounts/ and enable multiple sign ins.

Then, click on your account name in the top right. There should be a button saying "Sign in with another account...", which lets you do exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Visit Google Accounts and click the link next to "Multiple sign-in." After you sign into your first account, you can sign in with up to two additional accounts from the new accounts menu in the upper right hand corner of Gmail, then easily toggle back and forth between them. You can even open multiple Gmail tabs — one for each of your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be to open the second gmail tab using inPrivate browsing (Ctrl-Shift-P). This applies to IE9 only.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to solution proposed by The White Phoenix, you can do any of these:

1. Access one of the accounts through a proxy service, such as [hidemyass](http://www.hidemyass.com) or similar.
2. Open a new IE session by going to *File > New session* or pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>, then <kbd>I</kbd>. You can also create a shortcut to **iexplore.exe** with **-noframemerging** switch.
3. All of the above.

The above methods are applicable to all and every service that requires login, not just GMail.

Comment: No 2: didn't work